# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using Python 2 but I'm getting an error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'
```

when the script runs to the last line.  I don't understand which variable is still a string type.

```
from sys import argv
script, age, height=argv
print 'you\'re %r old'%age
weight=input('and i need your weight to calculate BMI, can you tell me:') 
print 'your BMI is %r'%weight/((float(height)/100)**2)
```

Comment: Why didn't you print out all the variable types and their values?  That would show it right away.

Answer (score 3):

```
from sys import argv
script, age, height=argv
print 'you\'re %r old'%age
weight=input('and i need your weight to calculate BMI, can you tell me:') 
print 'your BMI is %r'%(weight/((float(height)/100)**2))
```

i found the solution, it's because a formula after % must be in ()

Answer (score 1):

```
weight = float(weight)
height = float(height)
age = int(age)
```

You forgot to convert the input from string to numeric.  To diagnose:

```
print weight, type(weight)
print height, type(height)
print age, type(age)
...
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. can't float(height)on the last line turn height into a float type?

Comment: It certainly can -- and did.  That's where you got the "float" type in the error message.  I was merely breaking the solution into tiny pieces for readability.  If you use the values only once, you may as well do the conversions in line, and not convert **age** at all.

Comment: if so, weight is a 'int' and float(height) is a 'float', why there is still a 'str' in the line? sorry that i asked again and again

Comment: How did you determine that **weight** is an int?  Your code suggests that it's a str (all input starts as string).  Did you print the value and type, as I suggested?  :-)

Comment: yes, i really use print weight, type(weight) to check it and i get 48 <type 'int'>, doesn't this means that it's a int?

Comment: Yes, it does.  I just noticed the misplaced parentheses, myself.  Glad you found that.